# Zip two array and create new array of object

Tags: mongodb

hello all i'm working with a MongoDB database where each data row is like:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5cf12696e81744d2dfc0000c"),
    "contributor": "user1",
    "title": "Title 1",
    "userhasRate" : [ 
        "51",
        "52",
    ],
    "ratings" : [ 
        4,
        3
    ],

}
```

and i need to change it to be like:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5cf12696e81744d2dfc0000c"),
    "contributor": "user1",
    "title": "Title 1",
    rate : [
        {userhasrate: "51", value: 4},
        {userhasrate: "52", value: 3},
    ]

}
```

I already try using this method,

```
db.getCollection('contens').aggregate([
    { '$group':{
            'rates': {$push:{ value: '$ratings', user: '$userhasRate'}}
        }
    }

]);
```

and my result become like this

```
{
    "rates" : [ 
        {
            "value" : [ 
                5, 
                5, 
                5
            ],
            "user" : [ 
                "51", 
                "52", 
                "53"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Can someone help me to solve my problem,

Thank you

Comment: userhasRate and ratings arrays will in all cases have 2 elements?

Comment: yes,it will be just 2 element.

Comment: can userhasRate array have repeated values?

Comment: @MrS.Sharma You have asked the good question. The answer I have provided before has bug just like you said if it contains repeated values. But I have updated my answer and provided alternative way which now works even if it contains  repeated values. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @MrS.Sharma no userhasRate will not cointain repeted value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `$arrayToObject` and `$objectToArray` inside `$map` to achieve the required output.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      "rate": {
        "$map": {
          "input": {
            "$objectToArray": {
              "$arrayToObject": {
                "$zip": {
                  "inputs": [
                    "$userhasRate",
                    "$ratings"
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "as": "el",
          "in": {
            "userhasRate": "$$el.k",
            "value": "$$el.v"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

**Alternative Method**

If `userhasRate` contains repeated  values then the first solution will not work. You can use `arrayElemAt` and `$map` along with `$zip` if it contains repeated values.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      "rate": {
        "$map": {
          "input": {
            "$zip": {
              "inputs": [
                "$userhasRate",
                "$ratings"
              ]
            }
          },
          "as": "el",
          "in": {
            "userhasRate": {
              "$arrayElemAt": [
                "$$el",
                0
              ]
            },
            "value": {
              "$arrayElemAt": [
                "$$el",
                1
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: hello milan, this $map is working, but i have other field other than _id, how i  add it to my new data.

Comment: Do you mean you have other fields than _id and rate and you have difficulty projecting those fields ? If so, click the link below, I have added `name` field in the example and show you how to do that.
https://mongoplayground.net/p/vA55QoUk_pm

Comment: Also,your question's title is not relevant to your actual problem. To avoid down votes you should consider these things. Your title should be something like `Zip two array and create new array of object`.

Comment: Check the output of alternative method here: https://mongoplayground.net/p/PEdm8l03bkW

Answer (score 0):

Try below aggregate, first of all you used group without _id that grouped all the JSONs in the collection instead set it to "$_id" also you need to create 2 arrays using old data then in next project pipeline concat the arrays to get desired output:

```
db.getCollection('contens').aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      rate1: {
        $push: {
          userhasrate: {
            $arrayElemAt: [
              "$userhasRate",
              0
            ]
          },
          value: {
            $arrayElemAt: [
              "$ratings",
              0
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      rate2: {
        $push: {
          userhasrate: {
            $arrayElemAt: [
              "$userhasRate",
              1
            ]
          },
          value: {
            $arrayElemAt: [
              "$ratings",
              1
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 1,
      rate: {
        $concatArrays: [
          "$rate1",
          "$rate2"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: is this aggregate just work for 2 element? i think i has miss understood, about your question before. i have diffrent length not just only 2 element

Comment: Yes, in above aggregate we make 2 arrays while grouping and pushing the object using position 0 elements in rate1 and position 1 elements in rate 2 then in the next project concat both arrays to make one

Comment: but what i need is not just 2 element but have a different element, but thanks for your help btw

Comment: Do you mean userhasRate and ratings arrays can have more than 2 elements